# Real value Vs Prediction Value using Random Forest Graph has two different scales

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I tried to show a graph for Real Value Y and Prediction value Y1 in the graph that is classification-based (0,1,2,3), Y-axis looks good as it is 0-3, but X-axis shows a different scale. how I could fix it to show the same scale as Y-axis?
[image]

```
 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
 x = train_dt.iloc[:, : -2 ].values
 y = train_dt.iloc[:, -1].values #Trust_level
 x1 = test_dt.iloc[:,: -2].values
 y1 = test_dt.iloc[:, -1].values
 regressor = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 120, random_state = 0)
 regressor.fit(x, y)  
 Y_pred = regressor.predict(x1) 
 score = regressor.score(x1, y1)
 print(score)
```

And this is code for the graph

```
index = np.arange(0,len(y1))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(index,y1, label = 'Real Val')
plt.plot(index,Y_pred, label = 'Predicted Val')
plt.title('Real Val vs Predicted Val')
plt.xlabel('Real Val')
plt.ylabel('Predicted Val')
plt.legend()
```

how to fix this X-axis problem for being different scale as it should be (0,1,2,3)?

Comment: I doesn't get it. Why should X-axis be in (0,1,2,3) scale? Your real values and prediction values are in (0,1,2,3) range. X-axis is not, but that's because you're testing for >250 instances.

Comment: THanks. you are right it is because I have >250 rows in this dataset
but maybe I need another way to represent it rather than plot.